# Javascript: please help me understand this function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to understand this function for quite a while, but it just doesn't make sense to me. The goal of the function is to remove any numbers within the array of arguments that match the other argument numbers.

Why is it necessary to slice the array for the function to work?

Is args.splice(0,1) redundant? I removed it and nothing changed.

It seems like the filter function does the bulk of the work, but I don't see how it actually filters for the numbers...

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(0, 1);
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: @Rayon, it's  [1, 1]

Comment: Yep, the output is the passed array without the extra arguments, as the OP says. In that case, without 2 and 3.

Comment: It took me a while to get your question.. Reason is simple: First argument from `args` is always ignored as `objects` are equal(`===` is used in `indexOf`) only if they are referenced....

Comment: So whether you splice or you don't, as nothing is __`===`__ that item, it is filtered...

Comment: @Rayon, but it works the same without `splice` and with `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado – Nothing is equal to `object` unless they are referenced... So `array` is simply filtered.. `===` is just to explain how `indexOf` works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through it line by line:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

JavaScript's `arguments` variable is similar to an array but it's not an array. You can try this yourself: `arguments instanceof Array` will give false. So applying the `slice` method from the Array prototype will simply convert `arguments` to a real array.

```
args.splice(0, 1);
```

This is to remove the first argument, which is `arr` in your case.

```
return arr.filter(function(element) {
  return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
});
```

This will go through all the numbers in `arr` and will check each one of them if it exists in the arguments. When `indexOf()` returns -1 it means the element was not found in the array.

Comment: Yes of course it works. Because the first argument is an array, and you will be comparing the numbers with an array which always returns false. So in practice it doesn't matter if you keep the first argument or remove it. But it's more correct to remove the first argument.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Slice does not alter. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array.

Take this example

```
var object = {
'0': 'zero',
'1': 'one',
'2': 'two',
'3': 'three',
'4': 'four',
length: 5
};
var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call( object, 3 );
 ['three','four']; //output
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments, please see if it helps you to understand the function.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // arr just holds [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // args contains nested array with all input params [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
  args.splice(0, 1);
  //args is spliced and we have [2,3] in args
  //Filter arr=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] elements, condition it must not be in args i.e [2,3]
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Please refer to the below documentation to read about arguments object used in this function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

1. passe Arguments **[Array[6], 2, 3]**
2. Arguments after splicing or remove first element of argument **[2, 3]**
3. so closure function filters element which is present in first element of array with other two element. returning just **[1, 1]**

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, we need to understand the [`Function.prototype.call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

It *invokes* the `Array.prototype.slice` method on the **first** argument you pass to it, which in this case is the magical JS [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2Farguments), and then passes in whatever arguments follow.

Thus `Array.prototype.splice` is unnecessary, and you can just write:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var rest = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return rest.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

in fact, this has been implemented in ES2015+ with the [`spread` operator](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#default--rest--spread), so you could write:

```
function destroyer(arr, ...rest) {
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return rest.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `arr` we will have `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` and
in `args` we will have [[1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3]
The filter function loop over arr
and `args.indexOf(element)` will return -1 if `element` is not in args.
So, for the first time in loop the element value is 1 and inside loop

args.indexOf(1) returns -1 because 1 is not present in args because at 0 index we have array and at 1st index we have 2 and at 2nd index we have 3. So the condition === -1 is true and returns 1 to the array that is going to be printed to the console.

for next element, i.e., 2 in arr, the statement args.indexOf(2) returns the first index at which 2 is present i.e., 1 in args array. for likewise entire loop will be executed for `arr`